# SQL Server Computed Column as Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created a table with a computed column as the primary key.
Table is created fine.And here is the script..

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ARITHABORT ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [planning.A062].[RMAllocation](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL,
    [RMAllocatonId]  AS ('RMA_'+CONVERT([nvarchar](100),[Id])) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [RequsitionNo] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RMDemandId] [nvarchar](104) NULL,
    [HierarchyId] [nvarchar](102) NULL,
    [Season] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [VendorSupplierNo] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Year] [int] NULL,
    [Month] [int] NULL,
    [Week] [int] NULL,
    [Day] [int] NULL,
    [PlannedQty] [int] NULL,
    [ConfirmedQty] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [SyncId] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
    [RecordDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RMAllocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RMAllocatonId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

The problem is when I change this table (Add/edit a column ) using Designer View,it gives me the following error.

[image]

error

```
Unable to create index 'PK_RMAllocation'.  
Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'RMAllocation'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

When I use script to do modifications,it works. And Even I have declared the computed column as `NOT NULL`. How this happen??

Comment: Why are you doing this? I'd never had the idea of a computed column to be the PK...

Comment: That's the requirement

Comment: I think, that the computed column has no value at the moment of insert...

Comment: it's not at the insertion time. Its coming at design level

Comment: I've never tried something like this and - in fact - I think this **very** bad practice... probable a computed column is nullable "behind the scenes", because the value must be computed **after** the filling of the other columns. If there's any chance I'd try to change the approach...

Comment: Data insertion is fine. We are using this kind of tables a lot. Only in designer and in DBDiagram this error comes

Comment: So probably it's @Gordon Linoff with the right answer...

Comment: Just stop using the designer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something is wrong with the designer. SQL Server is quite clear in the documentation that computed columns *can* be used for primary keys (for instance, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx)).

My guess is that the designer is dropping all constraints on the table and adding them back in. It ends up adding them in the wrong order, so the primary key is assigned before the `not null` on the computed column. I have no idea if there is any work-around other than the obvious one of not using the designer.

Comment: The designing should not be done using the designer anyway and changes should never be done using it.. Scripts should be produced and put in Source control so that they can be moved to other servers.

Comment: The SSMS designer has nothing to do with this issue. The error is coming from the database engine. Please see Martin's answer for the correct answer. As I noted in a comment on his answer: This documentation ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191250.aspx ) says: "Computed columns used as CHECK, FOREIGN KEY, or NOT NULL constraints must be marked PERSISTED." It also states: "An expression that is nullable can be turned into a nonnullable one by specifying ISNULL(check_expression, constant), where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any null result."

Comment: @srutzky . . . If computed columns have to be `persisted` to be in a `check` constraint, then why doesn't SQL Server generate an error when such a column is used, but not `persisted`?

Comment: Two things: **1)** Are you saying that you are able to add a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on a non-persisted computed column? I just tried and received "Msg 1764 ... Computed Column '...' in table '...' is invalid for use in 'CHECK CONSTRAINT' because it is not persisted.", and **2)** I mis-stated that the designer was a complete non-issue in my prior comment, as it does appear that the designer does have _an_ issue, but not what is stated here. `NOT NULL`, while acting like a CONSTRAINT, is a property of a field and hence is not added later.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) (emphasis mine)

> A computed column cannot be used as a DEFAULT or FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint definition **or with a NOT NULL constraint definition**.

So it may be somewhat surprising that it works at all even in TSQL.

When the designer implements the change by recreating the table, it loses the `NOT NULL` on the column definition.

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL,
[RMAllocatonId]  AS ('RMA_'+CONVERT([nvarchar](100),[Id])) PERSISTED,
[RequsitionNo] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
```

Semantically this concatenation of a `NOT NULL` constant and a `NOT NULL` column can never be `NULL` anyway.

Another way you can persuade SQL Server that the column will be `NOT NULL`-able even in the absence of a `NOT NULL` is by wrapping the definition in an `ISNULL`.

The following works fine with the designer

```
[RMAllocatonId]  AS (ISNULL('RMA_'+CONVERT([nvarchar](100),[Id]),'')) PERSISTED
```

Comment: The documentation quoted here is referring to _non_-persisted computed columns. This documentation ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191250.aspx ) says: "Computed columns used as CHECK, FOREIGN KEY, or NOT NULL constraints must be marked PERSISTED." It also states: "An expression that is nullable can be turned into a nonnullable one by specifying ISNULL(check_expression, constant), where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any null result."

Answer (score 0):

At insert time the system doesn't know the new [id] value. You need a trigger that update the value later.

Comment: it's not at the insertion time. Its coming at design level

Comment: I see. The problem is that you can't have a null value for a primary index. In my opinion you can: 1.- Create a column for RMA in a view. 2.- Remove the compute column from the primary index.

Answer (score 0):

When two `Id` values are same, corresponding `RMAllocatonId` values will be same. When two `Id` values are different, corresponding `RMAllocatonId` values will be different. So making the `Id` unique is equivalent to making `RMAllocatonId` unique.

If you ask me, just put the PRIMARY KEY on `Id` where it belongs and be done with it...